# How would I write this in idiomatic Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have some code:

```
private fun getTouchX(): Int {
    arguments ?: return centerX()

    return if (arguments.containsKey(KEY_DOWN_X)) {
        arguments.getInt(KEY_DOWN_X)
    } else {
        centerX()
    }
}

private fun centerX() = (views.rootView?.width ?: 0) / 2
```

and I want to shorten it.

in the function getTouchX, there are two return conditions duplicated. (which is centerX)

I tried to do this:

```
 private fun getTouchX(): Int {
    if (arguments == null || !arguments.containsKey(KEY_DOWN_X)) {
        return centerX()
    }
    return arguments.getInt(KEY_DOWN_X)
}
```

However, it looks more like Java than Kotlin.

How could I go about writing this in idiomatic Kotlin?

Comment: Help us out by telling us what arguments is. It's not a straightforward map, as I'm not familiar with a getInt, so what data structure is it?

Comment: @Mikezx6r thanks for asking.
arguments is Bundle object which is using in Android Fragment.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Bundle.java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure where arguments is coming from, but a cleaner solution would be

```
private fun getTouchX(): Int =
    if(arguments?.containsKey(KEY_DOWN_X) == true) {
        arguments.getInt(KEY_DOWN_X)
    } else {
        centerX()
    }
```

The `if` only calls `containsKey` if `arguments` is non-null, otherwise the left side of `==` resolves to `null`. `null != true`, so it will return `centerX()` from else.

Similarly if arguments is non-null, then the result of `containsKey` will be used to resolve.

And now that there's only one expression, can use body expression format.

Comment: I had change answer for this.
Because getInt not returns null. so using containsKey is necessary.
Thank you @Mikezx6r

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably go with an expression function with a `when` expression:

```
private fun getTouchX() = when {
   arguments == null || !arguments.containsKey(KEY_DOWN_X) -> centerX()
   else -> arguments.getInt(KEY_DOWN_X)
}
```

You could also consider declaring `touchX` as a `private val`:

```
private val touchX: Int
    get() = when {
       arguments == null || !arguments.containsKey(KEY_DOWN_X) -> centerX()
       else -> arguments.getInt(KEY_DOWN_X)
    }
```

Comment: The `,`-syntax is deprecated, better use `||`. Also that way of `null`-checking is the very bane of java style ;)

Comment: good point, it shorted 1 line.
however 

    `arguments == null`

this looks long to me. (personal feeling).
Thanks though!

Comment: @leoderprofi : Where did you read that comma as pattern separator is deprecated? Can’t find any mention of it in the Kotlin reference. As for the way of null-checking, Kotlin is not Java, as long as the null check propagates correctly it is perfectly safe, and I think it communicates more clearly than using == true for null checking.

Comment: Android Studio warns for when without argument. It took me a while to track this down through the [source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/da90c21284a098bd6978c937be992e00f367241d), [Issue KT-5143](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5143). I never liked all the null checking in java, `b == true` for `b : Boolean?` expressions [is an idiom](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html) (at the very bottom)

Comment: @leoderprofi : Hmm, seems you are correct. Comma as pattern separator is discouraged for `when { ... }` (but not for `when(...) { ... }`). Weird that it is not mentioned in the reference.

Comment: combining with two answer I can write like this.
`private fun getTouchX2(): Int = when {
        (arguments?.containsKey(KEY_DOWN_X) == true) -> arguments.getInt(KEY_DOWN_X)
        else -> centerX()
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at just the plain Kotlin code, my suggestion would be:

```
    private fun getTouchX() =
        arguments?.let {
            if (!it.containsKey(KEY_DOWN_X))
                return@let null
            it.getInt(KEY_DOWN_X)
        } ?: centerX()
```

But if `arguments` is a descendent of an Android `BaseBundle`, you might further compress this to:

```
private fun getTouchX() = arguments?.getInt(KEY_DOWN_X, centerX()) ?: centerX()
```

Note: As the method signature suspiciously looks like reading a property, you might consider turning it into a read-only property.