# How would I write this in idiomatic Kotlin? - 2

Tags: kotlin, idioms

I asked a question:
[How would I write this in idiomatic Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49806453/how-would-i-write-this-in-idiomatic-kotlin)

and now I had an idea for short this idiom. like below

```
private fun getTouchX(): Int = when(arguments) 
     containsKey(KEY_DOWN_X) -> getInt(KEY_DOWN_X)
     else -> centerX() 
}
```

`containsKey` and `getInt` are `arguments`'s method.

Of course this is not correct idiom for `when`.
is there any possible way to do this?

arguments is Bundle class in Android framework.
you can see at below
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Bundle.java
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/BaseBundle.java

Comment: You did not state the type of `arguments`, which makes this question a guessing game. Again.

Comment: @leoderprofi thanks for advice. I added more information about argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information you've provided I can only give you this answer:

```
private fun getTouchX(): Int = arguments.run {
    if (containsKey(KEY_DOWN_X)) getInt(KEY_DOWN_X)
    else centerX()
}
```

If `arguments` is nullable, it can be like this:

```
private fun getTouchX(): Int = arguments?.run {
    if (containsKey(KEY_DOWN_X)) getInt(KEY_DOWN_X)
    else null
} ?: centerX()
```

Comment: oh great. I didn't know run can return value. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ice1000's answer.
I got that below idiom also possible

```
private fun getTouchX(): Int = arguments?.run {
    when {
        containsKey(KEY_DOWN_X) -> getInt(KEY_DOWN_X)
        else -> null
    }
} ?: centerX()
```

I might can use it when more than 3 predicate condition (if x 3)